# "Can live no more" vs "can no more live"

Tags: phrases, sentence-patterns, sentence-meaning

Is there a difference in meaning between the two versions of this famous phrase/quote:

> "Man **can live no more** without air than a fish can without water"

vs

> "Man **can no more live** without air than a fish can without water".

Incidentally, this phrase seems surprisingly hard to find on the web. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Live no more** implies *die*. Whereas it's true that a person would die without air, the point of your sentence is that mankind depends on air *as much as* fish do on water, so **no more** belongs before the phrase **live without air.**